# jQuery + WordPress: $ is not defined

Tags: jquery, function

The following code is having some problem with the jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function() {
            ..
        });
    </script>
```

If I include jQuery in the document head and then use the above code, it will work fine.
However, if I use include jQuery using the Wordpress function `wp_enqueue_script`, I get following error: `$ is not defined`.
I can see from the page source that the jQuery is loaded properly in the header.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `jQuery` with a capital `Q` instead of $ to make it work. Wordpress usually includes a script which calls `jQuery.noConflict()` at the end, leaving $ undefined.

```
jQuery(function($) { //jQuery passed in as first param, so you can use $ inside
   // use $
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the word `jQuery` instead of `$` and pass it a `$` reference

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // you can use $ here
    $(window).load(function() {
        ..
    });
});
```